# Знаки вопроса вместо русских символов

Tags: кодировка, php

Есть файл класса **class.employee.php**

```
<?php
    class employee
    {
        public function __construct($surname, $name, $patronymic, $age = 18)
        {
            $this->surname = $surname;
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->patronymic = $patronymic;
            $this->age = $age;
        }

        public function __toString()
        {
            return "{$this->surname} {$this->name[0]}.{$this->patronymic[0]}.";
        }

        public function __get($index)
        {
            return $this->$index;
        }

        public $surname;
        public $name;
        private $patronymic;

    }
?>
```

есть его использование

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <title>index</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
    require_once("class.employee.php");

    $obj = new employee("Борисов", "Игорь", "Иванович");

    echo "Сотрудник $obj недавно принят на работу";
?>
</body>
```

но там, где должны выводится инициалы, вместо букв выводятся знаки вопроса
[image]

Оба файла сохранены в кодировке utf-8 без BOM.
В чем проблема и как её решить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

из-за вот таких конструкций

```
$this->name[0]
```

Вы работаете с UTF8, это двухбайтовая кодировка. воспользуйтесь функциями mb_* для вырезания куска строки

```
    public function __toString()
    {
        return "{$this->surname} ".mb_substr($this->name,0,1,"utf8").".".mb_substr($this->patronymic,0,1,"utf8");
    }
```

Comment: Объясните, плиз, подробнее что за функции и как ими пользоваться?

Comment: Дополнил ответ

Comment: да, спасибо, работает!

Answer (score 0):

А если в .htaccess прописать

> ADDDefaultCharset UTF-8

Comment: у меня локальный сервер Winginx, как я понимаю, там другие конфигурационные файлы, .htaccess нету.